# Grails: How to Add Parameters to F:Table

Tags: grails, field

In Grails 3.3.9, the Fields plugin is used by default.

This generates the following in the `index.gsp`:

```
<f:table collection="${domainClassList}"/>
```

In Grails 2 you had access to each of the fields and could add parameters to the fields and even create a link out of the field as so:

```
<td><g:link action="show" id="${domainClassInstance.code}">
                            ${fieldValue(bean: domainClassInstance, field: "code")}
                        </g:link></td>
```

How do I use the id option with the f:table tag in Grails 3.x? I want to add a domain class property so that when I click on the code, I go to the record's show page.

Comment: I think the 3x approach to this kind of problem would be to override the template used by `f:display` by implementing a `_displayWrapper.gsp` or maybe override `f:field` with a `_wrapper.gsp`.  The docs do a better job now of explaining the conventions for where to put these overrides (see Chapter 3 - Customizing Field Rendering).

Comment: @npskirk thanks I'll take a look at that. I forgot to ask but I also need to edit the columns in the table as well by adding the `params` option to them. It looks like the article you linked to just has fields. How do I edit the columns?

Comment: @npskirk I'm sorry what exactly should I be putting in the _displayWrapper.gsp? I did `<g:link action="show" id="${TST_Customer.code}"><f:field bean="TST_Customer" property="code"/></g:link>`

I got error: `Caused by GrailsTagException: [views/TST_Customer/index.gsp:21] Error executing tag <f:table>: [views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp:14] Error executing tag <g:link>: [views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp:14] Error executing tag <f:display>: Error evaluating expression [TST_Customer.code] on line [1]: Cannot get property 'code' on null object`